# Why study Proper Maps?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

We invite the reader to recall that a proper map $f: X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X,Y$ is a continuous map such that for all compact sets $K \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(K) \subset X$ is compact.

Proper holomorphic maps play a large role in the theory of holomorphic functions of several complex variables, of which I am beginning my studies.

I am curious as to why we study these maps in particular? I am aware of the proper mapping theorem, which asserts that the image of an analytic space under a proper holomorphic mapping is an analytic subvariety of the target analytic space, but I'm not really seeing the significance of these results.

Any motivation or insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My 2 cents opinion. The typical non-proper map for me is the inclusion $D^* \subset D$. So in some sense, a non-proper map can be interpreted as a proper map where some points in the fiber was deleted. Once the map is proper, the understanding of the topology of the map is also more easy (for example when $f$ is a submersion $X$ is a locally trivial fiber bundle). There is also the proper base change theorem which is useful where you are studying a family.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet could you recommend a reference for proper base change in the analytic context (not for schemes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper maps preserve holomorphic convexity. That is, if $D$ is holomorphically convex and $f$ is proper, then $f(D)$ is holomorphically convex.

Comment: Proper and something else, I imagine.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez See page 4 of introduction of Remert and Grauert's text on Stein spaces.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only addresses the (general-topology) aspect of your question.

The topological theory of proper mappings is very rich and full of interesting invariants, the simplest of which is the [set of ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)). Given a connected manifold $X$ (or more generally a path connected locally compact space), the collection of subsets $U \subset X$ such that $X-U$ is compact forms an inverse system under inclusion, and the inverse limit of this set is, by definition, the set of ends $\text{Ends}(X)$. This defines part of a functor from the category of connected manifolds and proper maps to the category of sets and functions: for any proper map $f : X \to Y$ there is an induced function $f_* : \text{Ends}(X) \to \text{Ends}(Y)$.

As an application, if $Y$ has more ends than $X$ in the sense of cardinality then there are no surjective proper maps from $X$ to $Y$, because the map on ends induced by a surjective proper map is also surjective, as one can check.

One can generalize ends to a richer collection of invariants in the category of proper maps, namely the [cohomology with compact supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support) $H^n_c(X;\mathbb{R})$. This is connected with the number of ends by the theorem that the rank of $H^1_c(X;\mathbb{R})$ is equal to one plus the number of ends (I think I have that right).

Answer (score 1):

This is an intuitive idea on **proper maps** between *metric spaces*; and it is extendible to topological spaces which admits an [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) satisfying the Hausdorff's separation axiom.

---

Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be metric spaces, let $f:X\to Y$; $f$ is **continuous** if and only if for any convergent sequence $\{x_n\in X\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $\{f(x_n)\in Y\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

Otherwise, let $\{x_n\in X\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a *sequence escape to infinity*, that is
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,\exists K_n\Subset X\mid\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subseteq K_n,\,\forall m>n,\,x_m\notin K_n.
$$
It is easy to prove that $f$ is **proper** (as the *OP*'s definition) if and only if for any sequence $\{x_n\in X\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *escapes to infinity*, also $\{f(x_n)\in Y\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *escapes to infinity*.

---

**A little remark**: In algebraic geometry, there exists a notion of **proper morphism**, which is more complicated as one can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism#Definition).

Comment: Thanks your response, I am still not quite understanding the motivation. What is the significance of a map preserving that sequences escape to infinity?

Comment: You think to $(Xd,_1)=(Y,d_2)=(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$: in this (particular case) a *continuous* function is **proper** if and only if it is sends divergent sequences in divergent one. Is all more clear? P.S.: I'm writing by mobile phone, I apologize for eventual mistakes. ;)

Comment: Apologies if I am being unclear, I appreciate your time. I don't see why the property of mapping divergent sequences to divergent sequences is worth considering? What problems does that help us solve? If you are aware of the proper mapping theorem, I would appreciate some motivation for the significance of that result if possible. I think I need some geometric motivation (if it exists). What I mean by this is that a map such as a biholomorphism is easily motivated, since it preserves orientation, conformal maps are easy to motivate by Riemann's mapping theorem.

Comment: The property of being proper is important because in many situations properness is precisely the condition necessary for something that we want to hold — this is the same exact importance of essentially every other definition you will encounter. Proper group actions, for example, are very good group actions, and so on. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/fundthmalg/propermaps.pdf for a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra done in terms of properness of maps

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to make a list of places where properness is useful, really. A good criterion is that if something made it to a general topology course, then it is generally useful. I suggest you suspend disbelief.